# Module layout file not being used

Tags: magento2, module, layout

I have a simple module Alpine_AlpineCustom but it seems that my layout.xml file is not being applied properly and I just can't see why.

I can see via Commercebug that the layout file `alpinecustom_index_index.xml` is seen, but when I call my page it I see a "1column" page with "Create New Customer Account" and not my content. So either my layout is either not working, working wrong, or is ignored for this path block.

**My router, controller, template seem to work properly because if I put `$block->setTemplate('Alpine_AlpineCustom::alpine.phtml');` in my execute function things show as expected** without error.

It must be something simple and obvious between the block and the layout, a path or name mismatch but I just cannot see it. It is the right block name and template reference since they work elsewhere.

What am I not seeing?

Bonus question: why is it showing "Create New Customer Account"?

**Alpine\AlpineCustom\view\frontend\layout\alpinecustom_index_index.xml:**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Layout Alive</title>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Alpine\AlpineCustom\Block\Index" name="alpinecatalog" template="Alpine_AlpineCustom::alpine.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**Alpine\AlpineCustom\Block\Index.php**

```
<?php 

namespace Alpine\AlpineCustom\Block;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,   
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getAlive()
    {
        return 'Module Index Block ALIVE';
    }

}
?>
```

**Alpine\AlpineCustom\Controller\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Alpine\AlpineCustom\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory resultPageFactory
    */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        //$block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Alpine\AlpineCustom\Block\Index');
        //$block->setTemplate('Alpine_AlpineCustom::alpine.phtml');
        //$this->getResponse()->appendBody($block->toHtml());
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        return $resultPage;        
    }
}
?>
```

**Alpine\AlpineCustom\etc\frontend\routes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="alpinecatalog" frontName="alpinecatalog">
        <module name="Alpine_AlpineCustom" />
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/code/Alpine/AlpineCustom/view/frontend/layout/alpinecatalog_index_index.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Layout Alive</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Alpine\AlpineCustom\Block\Index" name="alpinecatalog" template="Alpine_AlpineCustom::alpine.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Note :**

> Layout Router = {front-name}/{controller-name}/{action-name}

Comment: I can't spot the difference, what am I missing? aha, the name.

Comment: so the layout blocks are per route not module - lets see if I can make it work

Comment: It still now showing my content in template as expecte. BUT it is still additionally showing me the header "Create New Customer Account" which I have no idea where it is coming from, any idea? Surely that cannot be the default title?

Comment: I think it's inherited from the theme